# How can I skip a System.DateTime XML value in XSL if it contains a specific Date/Time?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML output that contains:

```
<Datemultisegmentjourney type="System.DateTime">01/01/1900 00:00:00</Datemultisegmentjourney>
```

if no date was selected on a form.
I want to display the html showing the date only if it's different from this default value (01/01/1900 00:00:00)

I've tried the following:

```
<xsl:template match="Datemultisegmentjourney">
   <xsl:if test="Datemultisegmentjourney!='01/01/1900 00:00:00'">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
   </xsl:if>
...
```

and also tried

```
<xsl:if test="Datemultisegmentjourney&lt;current-dateTime()">
```

but none is working

Comment: Try changing `<xsl:if test="Datemultisegmentjourney!='01/01/1900 00:00:00'">` to `<xsl:if test=".!='01/01/1900 00:00:00'">`. `xsl:template match="Datemultisegmentjourney">` sets the context node.

Comment: The value you are outputting does not contain any characters that need to be escaped, so why are you disabling output escaping? `disable-output-escaping` is a very specialized feature that should only be used in very rare circumstances.

Comment: <xsl:if test=".!='01/01/1900 00:00:00'"> works just fine. Thanks.